# Mex cannot find MS SDK in Matlab R2016b

Tags: matlab, mex

My Matlab installation on the server I use has been updated from R2015a to R2016b and now mex does not work. When I type `mex -setup` I get the error

```
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. You can install the freely available MinGW-w64 C/C++ compiler; [...]
```

Whenever previously I have updated Matlab, I have not encountered this problem.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 is installed and working.

**More info:**

- The server is not connected to the internet as it contains confidential data.
- The visual studio installation has not been changed for the past many years and has worked through at least two past updates of Matlab.
- The environment variable `MSSdk` was not set initially. I have tried setting it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A" but to no avail.

Comment: It looks like 2010 [is no longer supported](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html) whereas it *was* supported in [R2015a](https://de.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2015a_SupportedCompilers.pdf)

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 is not supported in R2016b.  Please see the list of supported compilers for Windows here: https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html.  It does support MS VS2012 though, so you may need to upgrade your compiler or keep using R2015a.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you. This answered my question!

Comment: It is not supported anymore [Supported compilers](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html), sorry about that.